# eclipse manual code folding similar to visual studio region

Tags: android, visual-studio, eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

visual studio has an excellent feature for manual code folding by using regions. i am new to eclipse and android but cant find figure out how to do this in eclipse. i am missing this feature in eclipse desperately

has anyone achieved this in eclipse

thanks in advance

Comment: [Coffee-Bytes for Eclipse 3.6 & higher][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use eclipse Coffee-Bytes plugin over a year. This eclipse folding plugin can be configured so that it was identical to visual studio folding. Lock [this](http://themindstorms.blogspot.com/2006/09/eclipse-api-and-code-folding.html) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/academic-cloud/downloads/detail?name=eclipse-folding-plugin.tar.gz&can=2&q=). Hope it's help you.

Comment: thnx mate... gona download coffee-bytes and start using it

Comment: Hi, yes it's on 3.6. Why without success? Can you explain more about problem?

Comment: Note that as of Aug 2011, the plugin is now hosted here: http://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/ (although it is not maintained)

Comment: Coffee-Bytes does not work in Eclipse 3.6:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/any-good-code-folding-plugin-for-eclipse-3-6-the-coffee-bytes-code-folding-does

Comment: Doesnt work properly in eclipse 4.2 either. I keep seeing a new exception in my error log every time i click in the editor window.

Answer (score 4):

Manual code folding can be added by writing your own small Eclipse plug-in. What it take is implementing [two classes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fui%2Ftext%2Ffolding%2Fpackage-summary.html) and packing them into an Eclipse plug-in that registers onto the org.eclipse.jdt.ui.foldingStructureProvider extension-point.

This is probably not the awnser you were hoping from, but as far as I know the only way to add custom code folding to the Eclipse Java editor. From your question I see that you are mostly a visual-studio user and as such not familiar with Eclipse plug-in architecture, but depending on your experience with general plug-in architectures, extending Eclipse is (in small scale) pretty straight forward.

Comment: thnx mate... someday hope to code an eclipse plugin :-) for now will go with pasha's suggestion for coffee-bytes ready to use plugin :-)

Comment: @Raj Yeah I will also take a look at Coffee-Bytes :)