# Eclipse plugin to define distinct background colors for cohesive parts of a source file?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a plugin/feature in eclipse that enables you to separate parts of a java source file with distinct background colors? Preferably, this feature could be switched on/off.

This would come handy when handling extremely large source files. I'd assign different background colors for parts of the file that handle e.g. initialization, UI events, whatever. I think this would improve readability.

So do you know a plugin that can do this? Any other solution/suggestion is welcome that helps navigation in large source files.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of any plug-in that would paint the editor background in different colors based on the code, but you can improve readability of large files using code folding. Coffee-bytes is a plug-in that gives you the ability to manually specify folding regions based on identifiers in code. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144791/eclipse-manual-code-folding-similar-to-visual-studio-region/5145114#5145114) answer.

Comment: Thanks, this should definitely help.